# Safari 6 doesn't show scrollbar in OSX mountain lion

Tags: safari

This is so weird. Safari 6 doesn't seem to show a scrollbar on elements with overflow-y: scroll.

```
<ul>
<li>something</li>
<li>something</li>
<li>something</li>
<li>something</li>
<li>something</li>
<li>something</li>
<li>something</li>
<li>something</li>
<li>something</li>
<li>something</li>
<li>something</li>
<li>something</li>
<li>something</li>
<li>something</li>
<li>something</li>
<li>something</li>
<li>something</li>
<li>something</li>
</ul>​

ul {
    background: #f1f1f1;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

li {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background: #c1ffff;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}​
```

I don't want to force the scrollbar because of performance issues in my app and it looks ugly when it's always there. Does anyone know of a way to fix this?

Firefox always shows my scrollbar which I'm fine with and chrome renders it perfectly, only showing the scrollbar on actual scroll.

I've created a fiddle showing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/mWT3X/

Update: Confirmed that it does render in Safari 5 but not 6.
Update2: This is specifically related to the show scroll bar settings in the system settings. If I set show scroll bars to always it will work fine.

Comment: Am able to see, ya though my version is 5.1, nothing seems wrong with the styles and markup

Comment: Sorry, just to be clear, you do see the scrollbar right? That narrows it down to just safari 6 then.

Comment: Yup I can see the scroll bar, and btw if you don't want your scroll bar to appear if height is `< 300` just use `overflow-y: auto;`

Comment: Thanks, yeah I don't even care about that all that much, just that it renders in Saf6 correctly. I'm thinking this is the OS messing things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Safari 6.0 there was a [WebKit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=90052) that would cause elements with "overflow: scroll" set to not display the new overlay style of scrollbars. This issue was resolved in Safari 6.0.1.

Comment: Looks like this is the answer to the issue I was having. Thanks and sorry for the delay in accepting the answer!