# Scrollbars not showing on WebKit (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, google-chrome, safari, webkit

For some reason I am not aware of, one day the scrollbars in my App's DIVs disappeared.

I decided to finally look into the issue, but it's been days and had no luck.

Basically, you can scroll through these divs, however, the OS X scrollbars won't show up. If anyone could take a look and see what I am missing, I'd really appreciate it!

To replicate this:

- Go to http://objectsapp.com/ with Safari or Chrome.
- Use the search bar to search for: Inception
- Position your pointer on the movie poster.
- Scroll! (It will work, but scrollbars won't show).

Any idea why the scrollbars might be missing? (must be tested on OS X only).

Thank you!

Comment: is it because your `PageSwitcher` class sets `overflow-y:hidden`?

Comment: Hey Paul! PageSwitcher only makes sure you don't over-scroll on pages that are shorter than their siblings (PageSwitcher readjusts it's height to match the active Page in it). You can remove that property and still won't work...

Comment: P.S: Scrolling happens on it's parent: <div class="container"></div>

Comment: maybe this then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017546/safari-6-doesnt-show-scrollbar-in-osx-mountain-lion

Comment: True, I can force them to show from System Preferences and they do show up. But they used to work just fine. Display first, then hide. Show on scrolling... I need to go back to that behaviour. Trying to figure out what could be making OS X change it's mind, so I can trick it =P (iPhone shows them correctly).

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which version of Safari on OS X you're testing with so its difficult to determine what problem you're seeing.

In Safari 6.0 there was a [WebKit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=90052) that would cause elements with "overflow: scroll" set to not display the new overlay style of scrollbars. This issue was resolved in Safari 6.0.1. If you're using a newer version of Safari than that yet are still experiencing the issue, it's possible that you're seeing a different WebKit bug. If so, you could test the [latest WebKit nightly build](http://nightly.webkit.org/) to see if the problem has already been addressed. It you still see it with the WebKit nightly build, I'd recommend [filing a bug report](http://www.webkit.org/quality/reporting.html).

Comment: You are right, I did not include my versions. I am running Safari 6.0.2 actually, on the latest OS X 10.8.2 - I guess it's a bug, you are right. What a shame! I ended up hiding scrollbars and building my own. Solves the cross-platform issue anyways... I appreciate your input btw! =)